# How to deserialize the Json response and store it into List?

Tags: c#, json, api, httprequest, json-deserialization

I'm working on a webService app for the first time. I have an http api that I am using to get the list of URLs to download Sample.xml files. I have created an object class that contains the list of urls and I am trying to DeSerialize the jsonString directly into the List of URL. Any idea why DeserializeObject method is not working?

Here's my Code:

```
public class StoreGetXmlUrl
    {
        public bool Flag{ get; set; }
        public List<String> Urls { get; set; }
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    }

public static List<String> CheckForNewXmlFile(string storeKey)
        {
            StoreGetXmlUrl result = new StoreGetXmlUrl();
            result.Status = true;
            _logger.Info($"Fetching new file URL for storekey:{storeKey}");
            try
            {
               
                var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://execute-api.us-west-2.com/default/param?=" + storeKey);

                var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

                result.Urls = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<String>>(responseString);

            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                result.Status = false;
                string errorMessage = ex.Message;
                HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
                using (WebResponse response = ex.Response)
                using (Stream data = response.GetResponseStream())
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data))
                {
                    errorMessage = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
                #pragma warning disable 4014
                _logger.Error($"Verification of store key failed with message: {errorMessage}");
                #pragma warning restore 4014
                result.ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
            }
            return result.Urls;
        }
```

This is what the json response looks like:

```
responseString = "{\"urls\": [\"https://uswest2.abc.com/sample.xml\"]}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result.Urls = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<String>>(responseString);
```

The above line is trying to deserialize a string array from json below which is a JSON object that has a property named `urls` that is actually a string array :

```
"{\"urls\": [\"https://uswest2.abc.com/sample.xml\"]}"
```

So you should be deserializing like this :

```
result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StoreGetXmlUrl>(responseString);
```

Comment: But the object does not match StoreGetXmlUrl either.

Comment: @seesharper it doesn't require that all properties defined on the class should exist on the JSON. Depending on the response different properties the JSON might be populated. (eg. on error)

Comment: Yes but the case is wrong (url v Url). Or will JsonConvert ignore that?

Comment: @seesharper yeap it is case insensitive by default.